# Existence of a Tubular neighborhood of a hypersurface

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Suppose $H$ is a co-dimension 1 embedded submanifold of $M$. Let $X$ be a vector field on $M$ such that $\forall x \in H$, $T_xM = T_xH \oplus X_x$. Now I want to show that there exixts an open set $U$ such that $N \subset U$, $U$ diffeo to $H \times (-\epsilon, \epsilon)$.

The proof is supposed to go as follows:

Let $\phi(x,t): M \times (-a,a) \to M$ be an integral flow of $X$, such that $\phi(x,0) = id_M$, $\phi(\cdot,t)$ is a diffeo for each $t$, and $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \phi = X$. Then by the inverse function theorem, $\phi$ is a diffeo on a neighborhood of $U \times V$ of each $(x,0)$.

How does the inverse function theorem work? I understand that the construction is trying to make that the differential of the map land in TH and X separately. But there is no guarantee that the first part is in TH. Why can the local diffeo be elevated to a neighborhood containing the entire H?

Comment: What is the derivative of $\phi$ at $(x,0)$ for any $x\in H$?

Comment: Must it be decomposed into a vector tangent to $H$ and a vector in $X$?

Comment: Yes, best to think of this as a matrix with respect to (some) basis built on that decomposition.

Comment: I see, may I ask whether you have any idea why does a local diffeo solve the question?

Comment: Aha ... The problem, as stated, is wrong unless $H$ is compact. If $H$ is non-compact, the $\epsilon$ may have to shrink as you "go to infinity" in $H$. So, see if you can do it when $H$ is compact.

Comment: The only argument I can think of is that you can take finitely many such pieces and "paste" them together.  But how to guarantee injectivity and the smoothness of the inverse?

Comment: Getting a bijection on a suitable set is just point-set topology; checking smoothness is a local issue, and that follows from the inverse function theorem.

Comment: Yes, but is it obvious that it should be injective? It seems possible that you can have $\phi(x_1, t_1) = \phi(x_2, t_2)$ is those points are not in the same "piece".

Comment: Yes, that's right. So you have to shrink $\epsilon$. Figure out how to make the argument.

Comment: Can you possibly write an answer about the injectivity part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sketch of the argument that when $H$ is compact, we can find $\epsilon>0$ so that $\phi$ is injective on $X\times (-\epsilon,\epsilon)$. Suppose not. Then for each $n\in\Bbb N$ we have $x_n,x'_n\in H$ and $|t_n|,|t'_n|<1/n$ so that $\phi(x_n,t_n)=\phi(x'_n,t'_n)$. By compactness of $H$, we can find convergent subsequences $x_{n_k}\to x$ and $x'_{n_k}\to x'$. Then from $\phi(x_{n_k},t_{n_k})=\phi(x'_{n_k},t'_{n_k})$ we infer that $\phi(x,0) = \phi(x',0)$, and so $x=x'$. But, by the inverse function theorem, $\phi$ is a bijection on a neighborhood of $(x,0)$. This contradiction completes the proof.

Comment: What an elegant proof! Thank you so much. Just one more philosophical question. How do you come up with? Is there any similar construction in point-set topology?

Comment: This is a standard sort of proof technique. For example, this approach is the usual approach to prove that a continuous (say, real-valued) function on a compact metric space is uniformly continuous.

Comment: When $H$ is not compact, this may be of some interest https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54799/on-a-proof-of-the-existence-of-tubular-neighborhoods/58124#58124